# Use protected domain on Red Hat 3scale backend

Tags: url, jboss, redhat, protected, 3scale

I run an application on a local jboss server. Now I try to add its api as private base url on 3 scale. But i got the following error message:

*Sorry, this domain is protected*

Does anyone know how to use a protected domain as private base url in 3scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the moment that's not possible, it is a known limitation based on protecting the gateway itself from possible injection attacks